# For an interface, what is the difference between these two way?

Tags: typescript

Why do these two writings have different results?

PS: Without any tsconfig setting.

```js
interface LabelledValue {
  label: string;
}
interface LabelledValue1 {
  size: number;
  label: string;
}

function printLabel(labelledObj: LabelledValue) {
  console.log(labelledObj.label);
}

printLabel({ size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" });

let myObj: LabelledValue1 = { size: 10, label: "Size 10 Object" };
printLabel(myObj);
```

On `parintLabel({})`, we got a TypeError:

Argument of type '{ size: number; label: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'LabelledValue'.

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'size' does not exist in type 'LabelledValue'.ts(2345)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because in your first printlabel, your object is of type "any" so compiler do not check if the type is correct.

Official documentation : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any

If you use the interface, compiler is able to check if the object match with the definition.